# OS X Terminal: Add comma in output

Tags: macos, sed, terminal, xargs

I am trying to figure out how to add a comma between two line outputs of application name and application version.

Here is my present code and output:

```
ordepmod-mbp:~ ordepmod$ mdls -name kMDItemFSName /Applications/*VMware*.app -name kMDItemVersion | sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' | xargs -L 2
VMware Fusion.app 8.1.1
VMware Horizon Client.app 4.0.1
```

I cannot figure out the syntax to use that would keep the present command as simple as possible, while replacing ".app " with ".app, ". So the intended output would look like (manually edited):

```
VMware Fusion.app, 8.1.1
VMware Horizon Client.app, 4.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have VMware to test with, so I'll use `iTunes` instead.

**Simplest Method**

Basically, I am specifying raw output from `mdls` to get rid of all the extraneous stuff, then using `tr` to transliterate the NUL between the two fields into a comma. This is simple, but doesn't give you the space afterwards, but may be good enough.

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemVersion -raw /Applications/iTunes.app | tr '\0' ','
iTunes.app,12.4.1
```

**Slightly Harder, and more accurate**

Replacing NULs with `tr` is ok, but you cannot get both the comma and the space because `tr` only does *"one-for-one"* replacements. `sed` can replace the single NUL with a comma and a space, but it is not very easy with the non-GNU version of `sed` on OSX, so I would go with `perl` instead.

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemVersion -raw /Applications/Textedit.app | perl -pe 's/\x0/, /'
TextEdit.app, 1.11
```

**Wildcard Version**

Or, if you want to use wildcards, I would go with `awk`

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/*.app | awk -F'"' '/kMDItemFSName/{n=$2} /kMDItemVersion/{print n, $2}' OFS=', '
```

**Output**

```
App Store.app, 2.1
Automator.app, 2.6
Calculator.app, 10.8
Calendar.app, 8.0
Carbon Copy Cloner.app, 4.1.9
Chess.app, 3.13
Contacts.app, 9.0
...
Sonos.app, 6.2.2
Stickies.app, 10.0
System Preferences.app, 14.0
TextEdit.app, 1.11
TextWrangler.app, 5.0.2
Time Machine.app, 1.3
VirtualBox.app, 5.0.24
Xcode.app, 7.3
iBooks.app, 1.5
iMovie.app, 10.1.2
iTunes.app, 12.4.1
```

The `awk` command is basically setting the input field separator to `"`, and then every time it sees `kMDItemFSName` it saves the second field (which is the app name) as `n`. Then, every time it sees `kMDItemVersion`, it outputs the saved name and the second field (which is the version). The OFS (output field separator) is set to a comma and a space.

Comment: The Wildcard Version using awk provides the application(s), comma(s), space(s) and line breaks needed for my intended purposes. The other two options have no line breaks after providing the output of "AppName, AppVersion".